# What happened to su password?

Tags: su

What happened to the su password, please?

No passwords, including blank, works.

Also, how do you log in as the administrator?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing has happened to `su`. `su [<username>]` has always required you to know the password of the account you're trying to access. If you don't provide a username, it assumes you know the root account password.

And Ubuntu hasn't set root passwords for *years*.

If you're in the `sudo`/`admin` group, and can run `sudo` (which is what you might be confused with) you can run:

```
sudo -i
```

When prompted, you should enter *your* password.

I'd thoroughly discourage you from setting a root password. While that would technically allow you to `su`, root doesn't have a password for a reason (to stop things brute forcing it directly) so you'd be undoing that for no good reason.